# How can you force an opponent to provoke an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

I'm wondering if there's any way to give the fighter an extra attack by forcing the opponent to move out of a threatened square.

Does bull rush provoke an opportunity attack against the target? Bull rush is worded

> **Push** the target 1 square and **slide** into the vacated square

This link suggests it does: http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Bull_Rush

So, does a power with "push" give OA against the target? (Even tho OA specifically says otherwise.)

What about Master's Wand of Magic Missile from Adventurer's Vault? In it's description it says "with the force of a bull rush" but the property just says that the target is pushed 1 square.

Comment: Your link refers to D&D 3.5 edition, rather than 4th edition.

Answer (score 13):

As Jonathan mentioned, the SRD is D&D 3.5, not 4e. You can force a creature to provoke with a few methods, here are the most common ones:

- Dominating a foe and having them move or use a ranged/area attack
- Placing a zone or other effect the encourages the foe to move on their own: The fighter attack becomes the "lesser" of the two consequences. A good example of this is flanking with a rogue in an area the opponent cannot shift through, like difficult terrain.
- The Agile Opportunist Paragon feat from the Players Handbook will give you an OA under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My account hasn't been linked (even tho i used the same email address) so I can't mark this as the answer. can a mod do it? cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Forced movement never provokes opportunity attacks. So if your wizard thunder waves the baddie away from the fighter, the fighter doesn't get to smack it on the way out. Same if one PC bullrushes the baddie.
The best way to utilize the fighter's OA is to create situations where the baddie is "darned if you do, darned if you don't". Try planting a flaming sphere on an adjacent square. The baddie doesn't want to burn each turn but if it tries to get away from the sphere the fighter will get to pop it one.
Also, getting abilities that allow to you mark multiple targets will give you more OAs simply because there are more targets who can provoke them. Come and Get It is a really good one. There is an At-Will that lets you mark two enemies if they are clustered up.
If you start looking at powers as a way to hit and mark as many targets as possible you'll get those OAs you want w/o having to sculpt your entire party around it.